# iPhone: Safari vs. launch from "Home Screen" bookmark

Tags: iphone, web-applications, mobile-safari, homescreen

What's the difference between these two? Do they both launch Safari (with the exception that the home-screen doesn't show a URL/tool bar?

I've found weird quirks that appear in home screen version..do they have different rendering engines? For example, mailto: doesn't work in home-screen mode, and there are some small rendering/css-styling bugs that don't appear if I visit my web application from mobile Safari.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple is using two different Runtime Environments for the Sarari Browser when launched as a browser or as a Homescreen app.
The Homescreen environment suffers from multiple limitations:

1. lack of print, mailto, caching-support and the list goes on ...
2. in iOS 4.3 it doesn't have the new Nitro engine enabled, so performance will always be lower in this environment